# Simple X window manager

Tags: x11, software-rec, window-manager

I'm looking for a simple X window manager that :

- stacks new windows over all others on screen
- has no window decorations at all (no title, no borders, no min/max buttons)
- opens all windows in max mode

Comment: http://www.nongnu.org/ratpoison/

Comment: @jasonwryan, that should be an answer.

Comment: @SimonRichter I left it as a comment because a long list of potential WMs is not really a good fit for this site...

Comment: I think you can do this with `devilspie` and almost any window manager.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you are looking for some [tiling window manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager). Have a look at the [feature comparison](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Comparison_of_Tiling_Window_Managers).

Which one is the best is really a matter of taste. They mainly differ in the kind of possible configuration, like turning off window decoration and default window mode.

Comment: Most tiling window managers will not meet the stacking requirement by default. However, many will meet the requirements with configuration and more easily than a tiling WM.

Answer (score 3):

[evilwm is one of the most minimalistic window manager](http://www.6809.org.uk/evilwm/)

Answer (score 3):

I think the i3 window manager might be something for you:

> The i3 tiling window manager is a nice modern tiling window manager for GNU/Linux and BSD operating systems. It supports tiling, stacking, tabs, virtual desktops, and multiple monitors. You can do almost everything from the keyboard, or mix up keyboard and mouse.

Most linux distributions have it in their repositories, more info here: https://i3wm.org/

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [Matchbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matchbox_%28window_manager%29) window manager, it has one full screen window open at once (as you specify) and opens any new ones over it until you close them. It is very light weight and ideal for things like PDAs or set top media boxes.

The only exception is is allows small popups like the file chooser to open not full screen as they may not be resizable. I have used this with much success in the past and strongly recommend you give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

As @michas pointed out, you need a tiling WM. I'd look at [`awesome`](http://awesome.naquadah.org/).

My take on this question is that many simple tiling WMs are a bit *too* simple and `awesome` strikes a good balance here: on the one hand it's fully scriptable, on the other hand, the stock configuration script is just okay for day-to-day work.